# How to select "dots" in VS code by search bar function

Tags: visual-studio-code

For some reason i have in text "space dot space" Like this but without quotes " . ". I'd like to select it via CTRL+SHIFT+H in all files and fix it.

I dont know why but VSC selects me every character, mark, symbol etc where is space something space.

How can i select dots please?
[image]

Ofc i googled but i didnt find anything what could solve it

Comment: You're using regex mode, where `.` matches any character. If that's not what you want... _don't_? Or escape it appropriately for a regex match.

Answer (score 0):

For regex search try replace `.` with `\.`